# Run countUp.js when user scrolls certain amount of pixels from top of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Please can someone help me, basically i want to run the Javascript when #stats become fully visible around center of the page. Once the javascript has run once i dont want it to run again unless they revisit the page.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks in advance.

My Code is below.

```
<div id="stats">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <h2><span id="totalFranchises" class="franchise-number">108</span></h2>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<script>
var options = {
useEasing : true,
useGrouping : true,
}
var countUp = new countUp("totalFranchises",108, 256, 0, 3, options);
countUp.start();
</script>
```

Cheers,

Wes.

Comment: so you don't want it to run `countUp.start()` until they scrolled so that `#stats` is visible? I don't see any element with id `stats`

Comment: the first div has an id of "stats"

Comment: You have to check if the `stats div` is in _viewport_ or not, also add a variable that the first time which the `stats div` has come to _viewport_, the bypass the checking after that. for checking the _viewport_ you can use [this](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport)

Comment: Even I'm trying this go to this link if helpful: http://codepen.io/davidensinger/details/YPNyea

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently and I used the heights of the divs above the div that contains the countUp. If you want to understand more read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633221/document-body-scrolltop-firefox-returns-0-only-js) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_clientheight.asp). This if you don't want to use jQuery.

My solution looks something like this in the controller:

```
$window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  var bodyScrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop; //this makes it work in all browsers
  var height = document.getElementById("previousDiv").clientHeight; //the height of the previous div for example
  if (bodyScrollTop > height) {
    //start the countUp
  } else {
    //something else
  }
}
```