# document.body.scrollTop Firefox returns 0 : ONLY JS

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser

Any alternatives in pure javascript?

The following works in opera, chrome and safari. Have not tested yet on explorer:

http://monkey-me.herokuapp.com

https://github.com/coolcatDev/monkey-me-heroku/blob/master/static/js/myscripts.js

At page load should scroll down to div '.content':

```
var destiny = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
var destinyY = destiny[0].offsetTop;
scrollTo(document.body, destinyY, 200);

function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    if (duration <= 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 2;

    setTimeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 2);
    }, 10);
};
```

Comment: if possible in pure css even better!

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Try using this: `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. If I am correct `document.body.scrollTop` is deprecated.

**Update**

Seems like Chrome does not play along with the answer, to be safe use as suggested by @Nikolai Mavrenkov in the comments:

`window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0`

Now all browsers should be covered.

Comment: Awsome. This solution works for Firefox so I will throw in an if condition when loading on firefox. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work for Chrome. It's safer to use `window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0`

Comment: @NikolaiMavrenkov Thanks, I updated my answer. I thought Chrome should also be covered, but seems like they still won't comply with the others ;)

Comment: @Michelangelo Not working in my site, don't know why.

Answer (score 43):

Instead of using **IF** conditions, there's easier way to get proper result by using something like this logical expression.

```
var bodyScrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
```

Both parts return zero by default so when your scroll is at zero position this will return zero as expected.

```
bodyScrollTop = 0 || 0 = 0
```

On page-scroll one of those parts will return zero and another will return some number greater than zero. Zeroed value evaluates to false and then logical **OR** `||` will take another value as result (ex. your expected **scrollTop** is **300**).

Firefox-like browsers will see this expression as

```
bodyScrollTop = 300 || 0 = 300
```

and rest of browsers see

```
bodyScrollTop = 0 || 300 = 300
```

which again gives same and correct result.

In fact, it's all about `something || nothing = something` :)

Comment: This is exacly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank You for the explanation! Really helps people out, myself included

Comment: @John_911 That's major purpose of StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 22):

The standard is `document.documentElement` and this is used by FF and IE.

WebKit uses `document.body` and couldn't use the standard because of complaints about backward compatibility if they changed to the standard, this post explains it nicely

https://miketaylr.com/posts/2014/11/document-body-scrolltop.html

There is a new property on document which WebKit now supports

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement

so this will get you to the right element

```
var scrollingElement = document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement;
scrollingElement.scrollTop = 100;
```

and there is a polyfill too

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/document.scrollingElement

Comment: I've plugged-in mentioned polyfill and replaced `document.body.scroll*` to `document.scrollingElement.scroll*` in my code and it works fine in Chrome 52 and Firefox 43 on OS  X.  Thanks Anthony