# Take window to same scroll position on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to take the window to the same scroll position after a button or drop-down is used. Example of one of the buttons (#english) is given in the code below.

EDITED

```
f(localStorage.getItem("scroll"))  
    {
        window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(localStorage.getItem("scroll")));

    }



        $("#english").on("click",function()
        {
             localStorage.setItem("scroll", document.body.scrollTop);
        });

window.localStorage.clear();
```

This works well in Safari, but not in Firefox.

Can't seem to get it to work in Firefox. Anyone, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<script>

/*makes a new page jump to same scroll position as the scroll position when the link is activated*/ 

if(localStorage.getItem('scroll'))  
        {
            window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(localStorage.getItem("scroll")));

        }

$("#englishflag").on("click",function()
{
     localStorage.setItem("scroll", window.pageYOffset);
});


 window.localStorage.clear();

  /*END*/ 
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633221/document-body-scrolltop-firefox-returns-0-only-js) `document.body.scrollTop` is deprecated in firefox try `document.documentElement.scrollTop` instead.  You may have to insert some conditional logic to use `document.body.scrollTop` in Safari and `document.documentElement.scrollTop` in firefox.

Change your click handler to something like

```
$("#english").on("click",function(){
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    localStorage.setItem("scroll", scrollTop);
});
```

ALSO

If scroll does not exist in localStorage then

```
localStorage.clear(); 
typeof localStorage.getItem("scroll"); // "object"
```

If scroll exists then

```
localStorage.setItem("scroll", 1000);
typeof localStorage.getItem("scroll"); // "string"
```

If scroll is 0

```
localStorage.setItem("scroll", 0);
typeof localStorage.getItem("scroll"); // "string"
```

thus, unless "scroll" is explicitly set to undefined, `typeof` `localStorage.getItem('scroll') === 'undefined';` will never return true.

If scroll does not exist, its value is null

```
localStorage.clear(); 
localStorage.getItem("scroll"); // null
```

AND

```
null === true //false
```

so

```
if(localStorage.getItem("scroll"))  
        {
            window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(localStorage.getItem("scroll")));

        }
```

will scroll if scroll exists (and is a number of course) and won't if it does not.  Are you looking for some other behavior?

Comment: if you mean this:  if(!localStorage.getItem("scroll"))
{
    window.scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem("scroll"));
  
}  Its not working.

Comment: Sorry, you want `if(localStorage.getItem('scroll'))`

Comment: Thanks Matt. Sorry for the delayed response, b'n away. Need the page to scroll back to the exact same scroll position as when a button is clicked that loads new page.

Comment: Edited the code in my question to your answer. Its work in Safari but not in Firefox (on a Mac)