# scrollTop always returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I've tried using scrollTop as well as scrollTop() and it always returns 0. How can this be, I've tried it like this:

```
Template.myHome.events({
    "click .examine": function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        varPos = event.clientY;
        var yPos = document.body.scrollTop;
        console.log("Y coords: " + yPos);
    }
});
```

as well as using the JQuery version on several div's within and including the body tag, again all giving me 0 or null.

All I simply want is to get the number of pixels traversed on the y-axis as the user scroll downs the page.

Comment: `document.body.scrollTop` should work. Can you post some code?

Comment: @LGSon, I'm testing in Chrome

Comment: Using `event.pageY` worked in this scenario.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [document.body.scrollTop Firefox returns 0 : ONLY JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633221/document-body-scrolltop-firefox-returns-0-only-js)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Depending on the implementation, the element that scrolls the document can be `<html>` or `<body>`.

CSSOM View introduces [`document.scrollingElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scrollingElement) (see [mailing thread](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Apr/0108.html)), which returns the appropriate element:

```
document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
```

Alternatively, you can use [`window.scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) or [`window.pageYOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset). They are aliases and return the same value, but the latter has more browser support.

For browsers which don't support any of the above, you can check both of these:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop;
document.body.scrollTop;
```

```js
var scrollTests = document.getElementById('scrollTests');
var tests = [
  "document.body.scrollTop",
  "document.documentElement.scrollTop",
  "document.scrollingElement.scrollTop",
  "window.scrollY",
  "window.pageYOffset"
];
for(var i=0; i<tests.length; ++i) {
  var p = scrollTests.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tests[i] + ' = '));
  p.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).id = tests[i];
}
window.onscroll = function() {
  for(var i=0; i<tests.length; ++i) {
    try{ var val = eval(tests[i]); }
    catch(err) { val = '[Error]'; }
    document.getElementById(tests[i]).innerHTML = val;
  }
};
```

```css
#scrollTests {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 999999px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollTests"></div>
```

Comment: I've tested in FF and `document.documentElement.scrollTop;` works but not in Chrome.

Comment: @user94628 Chromium 51 needs `documentElement` instead of `body`, but if I remember correctly proviously it was `body`, so they might have changed it. Anyways, you should check both (use maximum, sum them, or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for advice, I resolved this using `event.pageY`

Comment: In the first instance, it always has given 0 but when navigating to other page and come back to the same screen, then it has given the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

This cover both html and body element, cross browser (tested on Chrome/Canary, FF, Edge, IE11)

```js
function getScrollTop() {
  alert(Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop));
}
```

```html
Bla <br><br><br><br><br>
Bla <br><br><br><br><br>
Bla <br><br><br><br><br>
Bla <br><br><br><br><br>

<button onclick="getScrollTop();">Click me</button>
```

Comment: @user94628 I am using Chrome now and it works. Which version do you have? ... and did you refresh page as i updated my answer once

Comment: @user94628 Interesting ... I use that and it works for me

Comment: I think this might be an issue with using it in the Meteor framework.

Comment: @user94628 So if you run my sample here at SO it works?

Comment: @user94628 How does the code look like that you run in Meteor?

Comment: I resolved this by instead using `event.pageY`, which gave the expected value correctly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function topScrollFunction() {
                if (document.documentMode || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
                  $('body').css('height', 'auto'); 
                 window.scrollTo(0,0);
              }else {
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
              }
            }
```

1. Added a condition for edge browser.Since you dont wanna impact the other browsers with the **height**
2. You need to **add $('body').css('height', 'auto');** and then check for **document.body.scrollTop** which will give you the correct scroll position value.
   Hope that helps.Hope this works for you. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following CSS to **body** tag

```
body {
height: auto !important;
}
```

then check for document.body.scrollTop which will give you the correct scroll value

Comment: Oh yeah ! My body was `height: 100%;` and scrollTop was always 0. with `height: auto;`, now scrollTop returns a value ! I guess you shouldn't use the `!important`, but find the file setting the height instead to change it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $("html, body").scrollTop();
```