# JavaScript works in Firefox but not usually Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have a smooth scrolling script that scrolls you down to a section when you click a link. The script has worked in Firefox on multiple computers but has only worked on Chrome on one computer.

```
link.linkName.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(scroll);
    var viewport = window.innerHeight;
    var scroll = setInterval(function() {
        document.documentElement.scrollTop += 25;
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= viewport * 3) {
            clearInterval(scroll);
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = viewport * 3;
        }
    }, 10);
};
```

Comment: That's sad indeed.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [scrollTop always returns 0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36227559/1529630). `document.scrollingElement` is not always `document.documentElement`

Comment: @Zygomorph why are you targeting the document html element instead of say document.body?

Comment: @BekimBacaj, unless I'm mistaken, it shouldn't matter.