# Vertical Scroll position always given 0 on iOS platform

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

After launching the app and scroll the page. When navigating from one screen to another through button action, when trying to keep the vertical scroll position of the page on button action using `$(window).scrollTop()` it always has given 0 on iOS platform whereas, on Android, it works fine.
If navigating to the second screen and come back to the same screen and then trying to get the value of `$(window).scrollTop()` it has given the correct value.

Comment: Webkit bug. Try `$(body).scrollTop()` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scrollTop always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227559/scrolltop-always-returns-0)

Comment: @peeebeee I already try $(body).scrollTop(), but still the same issue.

Comment: That answers for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227559/scrolltop-always-returns-0  is different, but I also try to resolve with this help, but it doesn't work here.