# Changing opacity when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

My goal is to change the opacity of a DIV when I scroll down. It's important that the transition is smooth!

- When the `scrollTop` of the body is 400, the opacity of the Test-div should be 1.
- When the `scrollTop` of the body is 800, the opacity of the Test-div should be 0.

This is what I currently have, but it doesn't work.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 400) {
      var currScrollPos2 = document.body.scrollTop;
      document.getElementById('test').style.opacity = -currScrollPos2 / 400 + 2;
    }
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
}

#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just syntax error. Replace '}' by ')' at the end of your JS code.
Btw, I recommend using document.addEventListener instead of window.addEventListener

Here is correct code: https://jsfiddle.net/ye082ae9/

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 400) {
                var currScrollPos2 = document.body.scrollTop;
                document.getElementById('test').style.opacity = -currScrollPos2/400 + 2;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Could you at least explain the differences or why it does not work with `window`?

Comment: Basically window is your browser's window and document is the HTML page inside it.  
You can find more detail here.
http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/

Comment: That link does not help at all. It does not explain, for example, why I get scroll events both via the `window` and via the `document`. In fact, they are the exact same events, because the scroll event [bubbles to the default view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll).

Answer (score 4):

You are close, but the `body.scrollTop` property [does not work in all browsers](//stackoverflow.com/a/28633515/962603).

I took the liberty of cleaning up your markup and code a little bit. You were missing a closing parenthesis at the end of you JavaScript, for example. There were also some superfluous rules in your CSS markup, that I deleted.

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/28633515/962603
  var scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
                document.body.scrollTop || 0;
  test.style.opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, -scroll / 400 + 2));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#test {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to replace `document.body.scrollTop` with `window.pageYOffset` to make it work.
See: [document.body.scrollTop Firefox returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28633515/3162554).

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var currScrollPos2 = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
    if (currScrollPos2 > 400) {
      document.getElementById('test').style.opacity = -currScrollPos2 / 400 + 2;
    }
  }
);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
}

#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, there is one little spelling error at the end. Just change **};** to **);**

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 400) {
            var currScrollPos2 = document.body.scrollTop;
            document.getElementById('test').style.opacity = -currScrollPos2/400 + 2;
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: There should be both a `}` and a `)`. In your code, the function is never closed.

Comment: it actually has **}** it's just one line above

Comment: Ah, I was confused by the bad indentation.