# Is there a Material UI component to hide half a paragraph for users that did not sign in

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a blog website, and I want visitors to be able to start reading any given article, but to not be able to finish reading unless they sign up / log in.
I remember years ago I stambled upon a Material UI tutorial that uses a component built for this specific purpose, the paragraph will be displayed, but eventually becomes more transparent until it is no longer visible (unless they login).

I tried looking for this component on google but I don't know how to describe it. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can post a full answer if someone else doesn't beat me to it, but you're probably wanting to set the opacity based on the amount scrolled. I couldn't find any libraries but here's some SO answers that are similar [answer one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569824/changing-opacity-when-scrolling) and [answer two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203777/div-opacity-based-on-scrollbar-position)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Div opacity based on scrollbar position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203777/div-opacity-based-on-scrollbar-position)