# Adding DOCTYPE html to my index.html breaks my javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to the top of my html file, my linked script.js stops working. However, it works fine without the doctype tag. It should add a class to my nav when i scroll down and remove it when i scroll back up.

Here is my javascript:

```
var myNav = document.getElementById('header');
window.onscroll = function () { 
    "use strict";
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 50 ) {
        myNav.classList.add("nav-colored");
        myNav.classList.remove("nav-transparent");
    } 
    else {
        myNav.classList.add("nav-transparent");
        myNav.classList.remove("nav-colored");
    }
};
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try deleting the use strict part?

Comment: I did. However, it still doesn't work when i add in <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Are there any errors firing?  Or it simply does not run?  I don't see anything obvious in the `onscroll` handler that violates strict mode...

Comment: You might consider running your HTML through a validator-- perhaps you have some invalid markup for that doctype...

Comment: What error appears in the console?

Comment: My markup seems fine; when I ran it through https://validator.w3.org the only error I get is "Start tag seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>."

Comment: Chrome console does not output any errors

Comment: _"My markup seems fine; when I ran it through validator.w3.org the only error I get is "Start tag seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>"_  That seems like it could be the problem-- why do you have markup prior to your doctype?  Try resolving that and you might solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `document.body.scrollTop` in HTML 5 is deprecated instead use `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

```
var myNav = document.getElementById('header');
window.onscroll = function () {
  'use strict';
   if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 50) {
    myNav.classList.add('nav-colored');
    myNav.classList.remove('nav-transparent');
  } else {
    myNav.classList.add('nav-transparent');
    myNav.classList.remove('nav-colored');
  }
};
```

more information [document.body.scrollTop Firefox returns 0 : ONLY JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633221/document-body-scrolltop-firefox-returns-0-only-js)