# Scroll to bottom Button show only if scroll more than 200px

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

**Button:**

```
<button onclick="scrollFunctionBottom()" id="hulk"><i class="ion-chevron-down"></i></button>
```

**CSS**

```
button#hulk {
    position: fixed;
    top: 55%;
    right: 35%;
    display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#hulk").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
});
```

Now to display block after 200 px, i am using this code but it does not work:

```
function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200) {
   document.getElementById("#hulk").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: How / Where do you call `scrollFunction()`?

Comment: `Roko C. Buljan's` answer below should help you. Just in case if you want vanilla JS solution : https://jsfiddle.net/bjmrvLw1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use inline `on*` JavaScript handlers, same as you hopefully you don't use inline `style` CSS.
- Use `$(window).scrollTop()`  to get the current scrollTop of your page
- Use `.toggleClass()` to toggle styles

```js
const $hulk = $("#hulk");

const toggleHulk = () => {
  $hulk.toggleClass("is-active", $(window).scrollTop() > 200);
};

$hulk.on("click", function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
});

$(window).on("scroll", toggleHulk);
```

```css
body {height: 300vh; border: 4px dashed;}

#hulk {
  position: fixed;
  top: 55%;
  right: 35%;
  display: none;
}

#hulk.is-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="hulk">Scroll Down</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

but you have to test on your target system/browser. And/or add also your version like

```
if ((document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop)>200) {
}
```

Some additiona info can be found at [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633221/document-body-scrolltop-firefox-returns-0-only-js)

p.s. vote for the other question/answers if they work for you :)