# How to change My div position on page-load and on page scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a top bar div under an element I am trying to show **when page reload it has `top:50px` and when user scroll page the position change to `top:175px`** as I have stick header too, but it is not working as  expected.

**it is behaving like this on page load -**
[image]

**and it has to look like this on page load -**

[image]

```
  window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };

    function scrollFunction() {
       if (!document.body.scrollTop > 1 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1 ) {
           document.getElementById("bar").style.top = "90px";
      }else{
           document.getElementById("bar").style.top = "175px";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your if statement is always true because I believe, `document.body.scrollTop` is always 0 (Correct me if I'm wrong) [document.body.scrollTop Firefox returns 0 : ONLY JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633221/document-body-scrolltop-firefox-returns-0-only-js). Just use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` alone:

```
if (!document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
   // Page load
   document.getElementById("bar").style.top = "90px";
}else{
   // user scrolled
   document.getElementById("bar").style.top = "175px";
}
```

Second of all, I'm wondering why do you want your bar lower when user scrolled than when the page first loaded? If you want your bar to always be on the page under your header, I suggest you should use css `position: sticky; top: *your header height in px*`

Comment: I just added `position: fixed;` `sticky` not working

Comment: What if we need to hide this top-bar at style.top <=5540 or we need to hide this after particular div?

Comment: Have you try `position: -webkit-sticky`? Maybe your browser's having with `position: sticky`.