# Fade in opacity on fixed div during scroll up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a fixed `div` fade in when the page scrolls. Using the code bellow for another `div` class and it works perfectly, however this fades out and I need to reverse it so the div fades in.

```
var turn = document.getElementById('turn');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/28633515/962603
  var scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
                document.body.scrollTop || 0;
  turn.style.opacity = Math.max(0.1, Math.min(1, -scroll / 400 + 2));
});
```

I have tried swapping the min and max value but doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Example with `fixed` `div` and fade in `opacity` during scroll:

```js
var turn = document.getElementById('turn');
updateOpacity(turn, 0);

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var limit = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  var scroll = window.pageYOffset ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
    document.body.scrollTop || 0;
  updateOpacity(turn, scroll / limit);
  randomFontColor(turn); // optional
});

function updateOpacity(element, opacity) {
  element.style.opacity = opacity;
}

function randomFontColor(element) {
  var randColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999).toString();
  var hexColor = "#" + randColor.padStart(6, 'FF');
  element.style.color = hexColor;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2600px;
}

#turn {
  left: 6%;
  width: 88%;
  position: fixed;
}

.highlight {
  color: yellow;
  line-height: 42px;
  background: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="turn" class="highlight">
  Fixed top div with Fade in Effect on Scroll
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i would like to change it though so that it begins at 0% opacity and as you scroll it changes to 1 (fully visible)